# How to use window function in controller (node.js)?

Tags: web3js, metamask, nodejs, ethereumjs

So this is my users controller to upload a file :

```
exports.postUploadFile = (req, res, next) => {

    var ethereumURI = req.body.ethereumURI;
    var abi = JSON.parse(req.body.abi);
    var contractAddress = req.body.contractAddress;
    let web3 = new Web3();
    web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(window.web3.currentProvider));
    . . .
}
```

as you can see when i set my provider with "window.web3.currentProvider" instead of to make my metamask pop up, i got an error "window is undefined" ?

So how to use "window" for backend in node js / express js? I am using web3.js (0.2.x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly, you cannot.

`window` is defined only in a browser environment. In your case, since you're running it through Nodejs, `window` is undefined as expected.

Comment: Hmm that's too bad, im just wanna make my metamask pop up to confirm when i deployed my contract or using some function with ... So is there any solution, to make my metamask pop up for transaction confirmation with Nodejs?

Comment: the popup is client side not server side. You can do moving your code on the client side which may be the correct place given your requirement